# sql table timestamp buffer

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm building a system which has notifications where if a user 'likes' something, the other user gets a notification to let them know and they gain points.

I have an `actions` table where events are stored, and a flag to say whether it has been read (whether the notification has been read).

Problems arise when a user continuously likes/unlikes the same thing (as people like to do, to break stuff). I don't want to add and subtract every time from the other users points, and I don't want really want to log every event of like and unlike, so I need some form of buffer that waits a while to see whether the end result was an actual like - and then process the event and show the notification.

The likes themselves have timestamps, so I could do something around that, but I wondered whether there is a better way of storing this info into a 'buffer' table and then calculate the end result there? What is the most cost-effective method of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user "un-likes" something, I would just delete the "like" event from your `actions` table, if such event is still pending.

If you want to implement something a bit more advanced, use a buffer table (perhaps [in memory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/memory-storage-engine.html), if you can afford loosing some events in case of a server crash) that holds events from the last, say, 10 minutes. This way you only deal with a very small data set to insert into and delete from.

Then create an [`EVENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html) that flushes records older than 10 minutes from this temp table into your reference `actions` table.

[edit]

On second thought, I think we could use the naive approach: insert into, and delete from the one and only `actions` table, but only consider records older than [your threshold] when displaying notifications (or calculating the number of "likes").

Comment: Problem is that its already in the actions table then, so the other user will see the notification that this has been liked, then if the other user then unlikes, it will disappear and their points will go down - which will confuse the person being notified, which I want to avoid...

Comment: @Tim I figured this out when I re-read your question (the part where you say "I don't want to add and subtract every time from the other users points"). Please see my edit.